# transferring data from an excel spreadsheet to an access table regularly

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a continually updating excel table, with stocks information.
The information changes each time i press refresh in excel.
I plan to use this information in access, however i don't know how to ensure the data in an access table is always the same as in excel.
How do i update the access table to hold the same data as the excel table currently has?
i am a very inexperienced programmer, so apologies.
do i have to save the excel document as an array ?
I have tried copying and pasting a new table each time i need it updated, but this is obviously hugely inefficient.

High regards!

Comment: You duplicate whatever is in your Refresh button inside MS Access, i.e. you still need to 'press' something to keep it up to date (or you can have it automatically refresh every X seconds). What is that actual data source - is it a web source or some kind of database?

Comment: it is a web source in the excel spreadshseet

Comment: So you should really not be moving data from Excel to Access, but from your web source to Access. Putting Excel in the middle is just going to complicate things.

Comment: Simply use a linked table. Access will always pull the most up to date information from the Excel file, without any additional coding. See [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-HA001219419.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes it can be done, and automatically. The following very good link from Microsoft shows you have to do this.

[Move data from Excel to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985982/transferring-data-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-an-access-table-regularly)

There's no "short answer" but as stated in the article "Connection information is stored in the workbook and can also be stored in a connection file, such as an Office Data Connection (ODC) file (.odc file name extension) or a Data Source Name file (.dsn extension)."

So what you want to do is setup that connection based on the information provided in that link and subsequent links. Good luck!